# Downgrade Nvidia Driver from nvidia-440 to nvidia-390

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 20.04, kernel, xorg

I recently did a system update to Unbutu 20.04 and then noticed that there was a newer version of the nvidia driver listed in the additional drivers applet. I decided to try installing the latest which turns out was a bad move because I have an older GTX 550 ti. Come to find out the only driver version that still supports it is nvidia-390, so I tried following the steps of apt purge and autoremove and then installing with

```
sudo apt install -y nvidia-driver-390
```

Though it seems to run ok, restarting still says it is running a manually installed driver and the resolution is stuck at 800x600. I see this output and noticed there is an error during the installation:

```
Loading new nvidia-390.141 DKMS files...
Building for 5.4.0-60-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 5.4.0-60-generic
Done.

nvidia.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
Error! Module version 390.141 for nvidia.ko
is not newer than what is already found in kernel 5.4.0-60-generic (460.32.03).
You may override by specifying --force.

nvidia-modeset.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
Error! Module version 390.141 for nvidia-modeset.ko
is not newer than what is already found in kernel 5.4.0-60-generic (460.32.03).
You may override by specifying --force.

nvidia-drm.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
Error! Module version 390.141 for nvidia-drm.ko
is not newer than what is already found in kernel 5.4.0-60-generic (460.32.03).
You may override by specifying --force.

nvidia-uvm.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.4.0-60-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod...

DKMS: install completed.
```

It seems it won't downgrade the version of the kernel modules because the newer (wrong) version is already installed and needs force to continue. I have tried running modprobe -r to manually remove the modules from the running kernel, but that doesn't  seem to help.

Here are the contents of /var/lib/dkms:

```
tree /var/lib/dkms/
/var/lib/dkms/
├── dkms_dbversion
└── nvidia
    ├── 390.141
    │   ├── 5.4.0-60-generic
    │   │   └── x86_64
    │   │       ├── log
    │   │       │   └── make.log
    │   │       └── module
    │   │           ├── nvidia-drm.ko
    │   │           ├── nvidia.ko
    │   │           ├── nvidia-modeset.ko
    │   │           └── nvidia-uvm.ko
    │   └── source -> /usr/src/nvidia-390.141
    └── kernel-5.4.0-60-generic-x86_64 -> 390.141/5.4.0-60-generic/x86_64
```

I tried running the following commands, but it didn't work.

1. Remove all the proprietary nvidia packages.

   ```
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt remove '^nvidia'
   sudo apt remove xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-440-server xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-440
   sudo apt autoremove  
   sudo reboot
   ```
2. Install the 390 series proprietary Nvidia packages.

   ```
   sudo apt install nvidia-driver-390 xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-390
   sudo reboot
   ```

In the meantime, I have no way to activate my second monitor or change the resolution from the default.

Comment: did you remove the other nvidia packages before?  `tree /var/lib/dkms/` please.

Comment: Added the output above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it to work by installing an older version of the kernel using synaptic. Here is what I did:

1. installed linux-image-generic-5.4.0-58 and linux-headers-generic-5.4.0-58
2. Edited /etc/default/grub and changed GRUB_TIMEOUT from 0 to 5
3. Ran sudo update-grub
4. Ran sudo reboot, being sure to press esc after the UEFI screen to enter the grub menu and select Ubuntu advanced -> kernel-5.4.0-58
5. Once logged in, opened a terminal and ran the install of the nvidia-390 using sudo apt install nvidia-driver-390 xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-390
6. Noting that it no longer complained of a newer driver in the kernel, I ran sudo reboot and repeated step 4 to ensure I was loading the correct kernel.
7. This time my screen resolution and second monitor worked perfectly, so I opened synaptic and searched for the kernel-5.4.0-60 version and marked it for removal and selected the kernel-5.4.0-62 version for upgrade. Ran the update and rebooted again, this time letting it start the default kernel which is now kernel-5.4.0-62. The correct driver was maintained and I am up and running again.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced this issue also. For me, GTX 820M is supported up to nvidia-340, but the kernel in 20.10 gets nvidia.ko version 450. For faster version downgrade you can use ***dkms*** tool itself.

At first, after driver installation uninstalls the current version of dkms lib:

```
sudo dkms uninstall nvidia-VER/XXX.YYY
```

where **nvidia-VER** - driver name (i.e. nvidia-390), **XXX.YYY** - driver version (i.e. 390.141). Then reinstall desired version:

```
sudo dkms install nvidia-VER/XXX.YYY
```

That's all.